# Session in GAE separated in comma's

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session

sample i have a list:

```
sample = [a, b, c, d]
```

Then I want to pass the sample to the session:

```
self.session['sample'] = None #declaring the session...
for item in sample:
   self.session['sample'] = str(self.session['sample']) + "," + str(item)
```

But the output is:

**None, a, b, c, d**

I want the value of my session['sample'] would be = `a, b, c, d`

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in one line instead of a loop with `join()` and list comprehension:

```
self.session['sample'] = ", ".join(str(item) for item in sample)
```

If you're happy doing it in a loop, you need to make the first item `""` instead of None:

```
self.session['sample'] = "" # Empty string
for item in sample:
   self.session['sample'] += "," + str(item) # Note I've used += here
```

`a += 1` is just a tidy way to write `a = a + 1`

Comment: Or simply `", ".join(str(item) for item in sample)` in order to avoid the construction of the list